# An approach to the Atiyah problem on configurations via real semi-algebraic geometry

Tags: inequalities, real-algebraic-geometry

The cross-ratio
$$ C(z_1, z_2; z_3, z_4) = \frac{(z_4 - z_1)(z_3 - z_2)}{(z_3 - z_1)(z_4 - z_2)} $$
has a degree $3$ analogue
$$ H(z_1, z_2, z_3; z_4, z_5, z_6) = \frac{(z_5 - z_1)(z_6 - z_2)(z_4 - z_3)}{(z_4 - z_1)(z_5 - z_2)(z_6 - z_3)}. $$
Fix an integer $n \geq 2$. Let
$$Z = (z_{ij} \in \hat{\mathbb{C}}| 1 \leq i,j \leq n \text{ and } i \neq j),$$
where $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \sqcup \{ \infty \}$ is the Riemann sphere.
Let $\mathcal{Z}$ denotes the set of $Z$s as above satisfying the following $3$ different types of constraints:

1. $z_{ij} \neq z_{ji}$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and $i \neq j$,
2. $\Im(C(z_{ij}, z_{ik}; z_{ji}, z_{ki})) = 0$ and $\Re(C(z_{ij}, z_{ik}; z_{ji}, z_{ki})) \geq 0$, for all $1 \leq i,j,k \leq n$ and $i$, $j$, $k$ distinct.
3. $\Im(H(z_{jk}, z_{ki}, z_{ij}; z_{kj}, z_{ik}, z_{ji})) = 0$ and $\Re(H(z_{jk}, z_{ki}, z_{ij}; z_{kj}, z_{ik}, z_{ji})) \leq 0$, for all $1 \leq i < j < k \leq n$.

We define a complex-valued function $D$ on $\mathcal{Z}$ as follows. For $i = 1, \ldots, n$, let
$$ p_i(z) = \prod_{j \neq i} (z - z_j), $$
where the product is over all $j$, with $1 \leq j \leq n$, such that $j \neq i$. Let $v_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be the column vector of coefficients of $p_i$, ordered say by increased powers of $z$. Define
$$ D(Z) = \frac{\det(v_1, \ldots, v_n)}{\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (z_{ji} - z_{ij})}, $$
where the numerator is the determinant of the $n \times n$ complex matrix containing $v_1$ as its first column, $v_2$ as its second column and so on.

**Conjecture A:** $|D(Z)| \geq 1$, for all $Z \in \mathcal{Z}$.

I even conjecture a stronger statement:

**Conjecture B:** $\Re(D(Z)) \geq 1$ for all $Z \in \mathcal{Z}$.

If true, then conjecture A implies both the Euclidean and hyperbolic versions of the Atiyah-Sutcliffe conjecture $2$ (which states that the absolute value of the Atiyah-Sutcliffe determinant of a configuration of n distinct points in either Euclidean or hyperbolic $3$-space is at least $1$), since if $Z = (z_{ij})$ comes from a configuration of $n$ distinct points in either Euclidean or hyperbolic $3$-space, then the constraints 1-3 above are satisfied.

This thus suggests an approach to the Atiyah-Sutcliffe conjecture $2$ via real semi-algebraic geometry.

My question is: how can I attempt to prove conjecture A (or B), assuming it is true? Can anyone think of some theorems which could help? I am aware of the positivstellensatz and of related software made by Parillo, related to sums of squares. I guess I could possibly try to use the latter to try and prove my conjecture for $n = 4$.

Comments and/or suggestions are also welcome.